# Change Website Overall Size

Tags: css, web, size, html

On HTML or CSS, how can I change the overall website size? When I use CTRL+WheelDown to 80% on the browser, it looks perfect but how can I do this on HTML or CSS files to make it default?

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with CSS:

```
html{ zoom: 80%; }
```

Answer (score -1):

1.You can use CSS attributes such as `height-size` and `width-size`. You can make a class with these attributes with values in percentage or pixels (your choice). Later use this class in div to apply conditions to content in division block.
2.You can also use Bootstrap. As it has a `responsive` class which makes it easier and efficient.

Comment: Could you please share the Bootstrap code? I'm very new.

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Comment: <meta> code should work good. Also link mentioned is for bootstrap framework. You can ignore link part though.